# Eliminar dos tablas relacionadas por ID

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `gallery_photos` (   `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE `gallery_albums` (   `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
```

```
require '../conexion.php'; 

$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];

$sql = "DELETE gallery_albums, gallery_photos FROM gallery_albums INNER JOIN gallery_photos WHERE album_id= album_id ";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($resultado){
    echo "Eliminado exitosamente";
    
    } else {
    echo "Error al eliminar";
    
}
```

Estoy trabajando en ese código para eliminar información en dos base
por ID, pero me elimina todo de ambas base, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: primero que nada pega tu codigo NUNCA uses imagenes, es mas facil reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Comment: Listo ya modifique el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cláusula `INNER JOIN` se utiliza para unir ambas tablas, y necesitarías basarte en una condición.

Tu tienes lo siguiente:

```
DELETE gallery_albums, gallery_photos
  FROM gallery_albums
  INNER JOIN gallery_photos
WHERE album_id = album_id
```

Y al relacionar ambas tablas, deben basarse en los `album_id` **de ambas tablas** (que en una tabla es foránea y en la otra primaria):

```
DELETE gallery_albums, gallery_photos
  FROM gallery_albums
  INNER JOIN gallery_photos ON gallery_albums.album_id = gallery_photos.album_id
WHERE gallery_albums.album_id = album_id
```

Y en el `WHERE` tienes que utilizar tu variable `$album_id`, que corresponde al identificador que desear borrar:

```
WHERE gallery_albums.album_id = $album_id
```

El código final sería:

```
$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];

$sql = "DELETE gallery_albums, gallery_photos
          FROM gallery_albums
          INNER JOIN gallery_photos ON gallery_albums.album_id = gallery_photos.album_id
        WHERE gallery_albums.album_id = $album_id";
        
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($resultado) {
  echo "Eliminado exitosamente";
} else {
  echo "Error al eliminar";
}
```

Comment: Excelente bro me funciono el codigo !! Gracias por tu apoyo (Y)

Comment: He algo adicional? como borraria las imagen en carpeta local por medio de unlink?

Comment: Buen día, si gustas podrías crear una nueva pregunta respecto a tu nuevo problema, así te daríamos información más detallada al caso.

Comment: listo ya hice un post nuevo (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando `INNER JOIN` de esta manera y me comentas si te funcionó:

```html
  DELETE album, fotos FROM album
INNER JOIN fotos ON album.ID = fotos.ID
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Hola, hice los cambios basado en tu code y me lanza el else(Error al eliminar)

Comment: hice una correccion en el codigo, actualiza el tuyo tambien

Comment: @Noveember y no olvides poner en el where el ID del album que quieres eliminar

Comment: ejemplo: WHERE album.id = 1 de esta manera solo te eliminara el ID indicado y no todos

Comment: lo que pasa es lo siguiente en la tabla gallery_photos van las ruta ID de las fotos relacionada con el ID (gallery_albums) deseo elimnar las ruta por ID

Answer (score 0):

en tu código no estas haciendo uso del valor *`$album_id`*, el cual corresponde al identificador que desear borrar, es por ello que se están eliminado ambas tablas.

En tu condición *`WHERE`*, debes de incluir también a que *`$album_id`* deseas eliminar.